# MYSQL query AND clause

Tags: mysql

I have this table. I want to filter those ids that have specific features ids.

```
+------------+-------------------+
| id         | feature_id        |
+------------+-------------------+
| 1280230    |                21 |
| 1280230    |                22 |
| 1280230    |                16 |
| 20412TH    |                36 |
| 20412TH    |                41 |
| 20412TH    |                18 |
| 34173TH    |                36 |
| 34173TH    |                40 |
| 37282TH    |                16 |
| 37282TH    |                18 |
| 37282TH    |                38 |
| 37282TH    |                40 |
| 39341TH    |                41 |
| 1244064    |                16 |
| 1244064    |                18 |
+------------+-------------------+
```

For example

ids that have features 21 and 22 => 1280230

ids that have features 16 and 18 => 37282TH, 1244064

I wrote following query but this does not fetch correct results.

```
SELECT `id`, `feature_id` FROM features WHERE `feature_id`=16 AND `feature_id`=18
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single record can not have 2 different values at the same time. So you have to build groups and look at the whole group.

```
SELECT id 
FROM features 
WHERE feature_id in (16,18)
group by id
having count(distinct feature_id) = 2
```

You need to group by the `id` and then take only the records that have these `feature_id`s. With the `having` clause you can make sure you take only those `id`s that have those 2 `feature_id`s

Comment: and note that if DISTINCT is required in this particular instance, then you probably have bigger problems! ;-)

Comment: Thanks I dont need it :)